# Fragment cannot be cast to an android.app.activity on Notification click

Tags: android, android-fragments, classcastexception

I have a notification manager in a fragment, it works fine until you click on it, where it is suppose to open up Fragment_02 class wherever it is clicked (be it from the home screen, another fragment or activity)

code below:

```
            private void pushNotification(int Request_ContactIntTotal) {

            NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (Request_ContactIntTotal == 0)
            {
                NM.cancelAll();
            }
            else
            {
                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    builder.setContentTitle("Message Notification");
                    uilder.setContentText(Request_ContactIntTotal + " unread messages");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Fragment_02.class);
                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getActivity());
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Fragment_02.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    NM.notify(0,builder.build());
            }
        }
```

notification click gives error: Fragment_02 Cannot Be Cast To Android App Activity

Logcat:

```
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596): Process: com.mypackage.myapp, PID: 3596
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.Fragment_02}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.myapp.Fragment_02 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.myapp.Fragment_02 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
08-01 21:04:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(3596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
```

Comment: Update your question will complete LogCat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment cannot be cast to an android.app.activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705146/fragment-cannot-be-cast-to-an-android-app-activity)

Answer (score 0):

It is a fragment. So you can't open it as you wrote

Try to:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment_02 fragment = new Fragment_02();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) says that `addParentStack` can take 3 different parameters not include a fragment. My suggestion is calling `addParentStack` with an activity class and start fragment in activity.